# How can I line up a GeoJSON world map with Leaflet so that coordinates line up?

Tags: leaflet, geojson

Lets say I want to use Leaflet offline by rendering a GeoJSON world map generated with a tool like the one found here: https://geojson-maps.ash.ms/. In [Leaflet's documentation on GeoJSON](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#geojson) it looks like I'd use the option `coordsToLatLng` to do this, like:

```
L.geoJSON(data, {
    coordsToLatLng: function () {
        
    }
})
```

The documentation on that `coordsToLatLng` func are as follows:

> Creates a LatLng object from an array of 2 numbers (longitude,
> latitude) or 3 numbers (longitude, latitude, altitude) used in GeoJSON
> for points.

But I don't think it's immediately clear how I would know how to map a global GeoJSON object based on that. Would my only option be trial and error, or is there a more pragmatic approach?

Edit: The issue is 2D maps of a 3D sphere are warped into a myriad of different styles, each with unique functions to map lat / lon coords to the warping of the map, right? Assuming I can find the correct algorithm for conversion based on the GeoJSON map I have, that documentation still doesn't explain clearly what the syntax, input output for that `coordsToLatLng` func.

How is that function used exactly, and bonus points for naming the algorithms used by different map tranform styles to convert to lat/lon, for example to the map style used for [the GeoJSON generator I linked above](https://geojson-maps.ash.ms/).

Comment: Please can you kindly explain again what is your concern? In the case of the website you reference, it produces compliant GeoJSON data, in particular all coordinates are expressed in default WGS84 CRS (common lng-lat), and align with the vast majority of Tile sources on the web (Web Mercator projection). As explained in FalkeDesign's answer, there is no need for tweaking in that case. You might be confused with the variety of projections and CRS, which is a big different topic, and handled differently in Leaflet. Look for these in GIS Stack Exchange and OSM wiki.

Answer (score 2):

Your linked page generates all for you:

```
<script>
        var myGeoJSONPath = 'path/to/mymap.geo.json';
        var myCustomStyle = {
            stroke: false,
            fill: true,
            fillColor: '#fff',
            fillOpacity: 1
        }
        $.getJSON(myGeoJSONPath,function(data){
            var map = L.map('map').setView([39.74739, -105], 4);

            L.geoJson(data, {
                clickable: false,
                style: myCustomStyle
            }).addTo(map);
        })
    </script>
```

You don't need to set the `coordsToLatLng`, it is a predefined function which can be overwritten. Look into: [GeoJSON-src](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/layer/GeoJSON.js#L234)

Comment: But the issue is 2D maps of a 3D sphere are warped into a myriad of different styles, each with unique functions to map lat / long coords to the warping of the map, right? Assuming I can find the correct algorithm for conversion based on the GeoJSON map I have, that documentation still doesnt explain clearly what the syntax, input output for that `coordsToLatLng` func.